# Splitting my code into functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I need to mark seats entered by user with X and then display the airplane layout (the array) again with the marked seats and repeat that every time. This is my code, I am kinda stuck. If you can please help me cut it down into two functions: first function should print out the array and the second function should takes user input and mark seats then call in the previous function to refresh the display.

My output should be something like this:

> ```
> 1 X B C D
>
> 2 A X C D
>
> 3 A B C D
>
> 4 A B X D
>
> 5 A B C D
>
> 6 A B C D
>
> 7 A B C D
> ```

My code is:

```
 #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;


    int main ()
    {
        int rowNumber=-1, columnNumber=-1;
        char columnLetter;
        char airplane[7][4] = {{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
         {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
         {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
         {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
         {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
         {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
         {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}};

         for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
         { 
             cout<<i+1<<"\t";

             for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
             {
                 cout<<airplane[i][j]<<"\t";   
             }

             cout<<"\n";
         }

       do
       {
       cout<<"Enter row number:"<<endl;
       cin>>rowNumber;
       }while ((rowNumber<1)||(rowNumber>7));

       do
       {
       cout<<"Enter column letter:"<<endl;
       cin>>columnLetter;
       }while (columnLetter!='A'&&columnLetter!='B'&&columnLetter!='C'&&columnLetter!='D');

       if (columnLetter=='A')
       {
          columnNumber=0;
       }
       else if (columnLetter=='B')
       {
          columnNumber=1;
       }
       if (columnLetter=='C')
       {
          columnNumber=2;
       }
       else if (columnLetter=='D')
       {
          columnNumber=3;
       }

       airplane[rowNumber][columnNumber]='X';

           system ("PAUSE");
           return 0;
    }
```

I tried this but it doesn't compile so I can't move to the next function that prints the marked seats:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void fillArray (char array[][4]);

int main ()
{
   char airplane[7][4] = {{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
     {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
     {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
     {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
     {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
     {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
     {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}};

fillArray (airplane[][4]);     


       system ("PAUSE");
       return 0;
}

void fillArray (char array[][4])
{


     for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
     { 
         cout<<i+1<<"\t";

         for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
         {
             cout<<array[i][j]<<"\t";   
         }

         cout<<"\n";
     }
     return;
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: why wont your function compile? what error do you get?

Comment: Instead of `if (columnLetter=='A')..  else if(columnLetter='B')..`
        Use `switch(columnLetter)`

Comment: Link us to your code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/)?

Comment: Link on ideone: http://ideone.com/hAtMwz#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 16 should be `fillArray (airplane);` instead of `fillArray (airplane[][4]);`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now I can finally move to the next part of the program

Comment: Also now that I have that done, I am trying to make it such after displaying the seats available (the array), the program prompts user for the seat desired and then marks it with 'X', and then the display of available seats is updated. This has to continues till all seats are filled or until the user signals that the program should end. If the user types in a seat that is 
already assigned (marked with 'X'), the program should say that that seat is occupied and ask for another choice.

Comment: I dunno where I should start, my current program is below. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use a chat room (C++) to discuss more on this. Add me to that chat if need be.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to talk on the chat but thx anyways. I got most of it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void fillArray (char array[][4]);
void getSeat (char array[][4]);

int main ()
{
   char airplane[7][4] = {{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
     {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
     {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
     {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
     {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
     {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
     {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}};

     fillArray (airplane);
     getSeat (airplane);
     fillArray (airplane);



       system ("PAUSE");
       return 0;
}

void fillArray (char array[][4])
{


     for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
     { 
         cout<<i+1<<"\t";

         for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
         {
             cout<<array[i][j]<<"\t";   
         }

         cout<<"\n";
     }
     return;
}

void getSeat (char array[][4])
{
     int rowNumber=-1, columnNumber=-1;
    char columnLetter;
  do
   {
      cout<<"Enter row number:"<<endl;
      cin>>rowNumber;
      rowNumber=rowNumber-1;
   }while ((rowNumber<1)||(rowNumber>7));

   do
   {
      cout<<"Enter column letter:"<<endl;
      cin>>columnLetter;
   }while (columnLetter!='A'&&columnLetter!='B'&&columnLetter!='C'&&columnLetter!='D');

   if (columnLetter=='A')
   {
      columnNumber=0;
   }
   else if (columnLetter=='B')
   {
      columnNumber=1;
   }
   if (columnLetter=='C')
   {
      columnNumber=2;
   }
   else if (columnLetter=='D')
   {
      columnNumber=3;
   }

   array[rowNumber][columnNumber]='X';
   return;
}
```